# Unknown Loops in Read call of struct file_operations

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to create a virtual car as a kernel module(for practicing).
I have a read call back assigned with struct file_operations.
Here's my read method

```
 ssize_t vcar_read(struct file *file,char __user *buf,size_t len,loff_t *offset){

    int byte_to_read,maxbyte,byte_Read;
    printk(KERN_INFO "[VCAR] Starting reading Car's Status\n");
    maxbyte=ramspace - *offset;
    byte_to_read=maxbyte>len?len:maxbyte;
    if(byte_to_read==0)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO"[VCAR] Reached End of message\n");
    }
        sprintf(ramdisk,"Current Status of Virtual Car \n\
            Direction:%s\n\
            Speed:%lf\n\
            Accelarating With:%d\n \
            Maxspeed:%d\n",getDirection(vcar->direction)
            ,vcar->speed,vcar->accelaration,vcar->maxspeed);
        byte_Read=byte_to_read-copy_to_user(buf,ramdisk+*offset,byte_to_read);
        *offset+=byte_Read;
        printk(KERN_INFO "[VCAR] Car's Status Copied to userspace\n");
        return strlen(ramdisk);
}
```

When i tried to read the default values using cat then output is correct one but it also including unwanted strings, seems like its a memory leak or i'm mistakenly reading other's memory.

## Here's Output

```
root@anandlinux:/dev# more "Virtual_Car"
Current Status of Virtual Car 
                        Direction:UNKOWN
                        Speed:%f
                        Accelarating With:10
                        Maxspeed:100


dComposxMdComponentLevelsponentLevelAtaSmartBlobLevelrtBlobdComposxMdComponentLevelsponentLevelAtaSmartBlobLevelrtBlobdComposxMdComponentLevelsponentLevelAtaSmartBlobLevelrtBlobdComposxMdCompodComposxMdComponentLevelsponentLevelAtaSmartBlobLevelrtBlobdComposxMdComponentLevelsponentLevelAtaSmartBlobLevelr
```

## The dmesg shows that read call back goes in loop. Here's output of dmesg

```
[ 8690.506307] [VCAR] Starting ramdisk Allocation
[ 8690.506323] [VCAR] Ramdisk Allocated
[ 8690.506326] [VCAR] Opening File
[ 8690.506366] [VCAR] Starting reading Car's Status
[ 8690.506384] [VCAR] Car's Status Copied to userspace
[ 8690.506603] [VCAR] Starting reading Car's Status
[ 8690.506610] [VCAR] Car's Status Copied to userspace
[ 8690.506631] [VCAR] Starting reading Car's Status
[ 8690.506637] [VCAR] Car's Status Copied to userspace
[ 8690.506657] [VCAR] Starting reading Car's Status
[ 8690.506662] [VCAR] Car's Status Copied to userspace
[ 8690.506681] [VCAR] Starting reading Car's Status
[ 8690.506687] [VCAR] Car's Status Copied to userspace
[ 8690.506706] [VCAR] Starting reading Car's Status
[ 8690.506712] [VCAR] Car's Status Copied to userspace
[ 8690.506731] [VCAR] Starting reading Car's Status
[ 8690.506736] [VCAR] Car's Status Copied to userspace
[ 8690.506756] [VCAR] Starting reading Car's Status
[ 8690.506761] [VCAR] Car's Status Copied to userspace
[ 8690.506793] [VCAR] Starting reading Car's Status
[ 8690.506799] [VCAR] Car's Status Copied to userspace
[ 8691.399452] [VCAR] Releasing Ramdisk
```

please help me finding the bug.
Complete code is here http://kgcorner.com/code/car.c

Comment: Well, for one, it seems you are not NULL-terminating your output, which will likely cause issues for `strlen()`, which will pass its issues back to the user.... But, also, there are several variables there that we can't see definitions of, and so we can only guess what they really are...

Comment: I've added link to the complete code

Answer (score 0):

i solved it ultimately and got rid of a misunderstanding.
Actually read function returns the number of bytes read (i knew this)
It'll be recalled until it returns 0 (didn't knew this).
I have updated code on the same link.
http://kgcorner.com/code/car.c